# How to force working GraalVM javadoc examples?

Tags: graalvm

I can't force to work examples from GraalVM [javadoc](https://www.graalvm.org/sdk/javadoc/org/graalvm/polyglot/Context.html#asValue-java.lang.Object-) for method `public Value asValue(Object hostValue)`

```
Basic Examples: The following assertion statements always hold:

 Context context = Context.create();
 assert context.asValue(null).isNull();
 assert context.asValue(42).isNumber();
 assert context.asValue("42").isString();
 assert context.asValue('c').isString();
 assert context.asValue(new String[0]).hasArrayElements();
 assert context.asValue(new ArrayList<>()).isHostObject();
 assert context.asValue(new ArrayList<>()).hasArrayElements();
 assert context.asValue((Supplier) () -> 42).execute().asInt() == 42;
```

because some asserts are failed (`hasArrayElements()` and `Functional Interface`):

My java class:

```
$ cat Test.java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Supplier;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Context;
import org.graalvm.polyglot.Value;

public class Test {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    try ( Context context = Context.create() ) {
    assert context.asValue(null).isNull();
    assert context.asValue(42).isNumber();
    assert context.asValue("42").isString();
    assert context.asValue('c').isString();
    assert context.asValue(new String[0]).hasArrayElements() : "String[].hasArrayElements() failed";
    assert context.asValue(new ArrayList<>()).isHostObject();
    assert context.asValue(new ArrayList<>()).hasArrayElements();
    assert context.asValue((Supplier) () -> 42).execute().asInt() == 42;
    }
  }
}
```

result:

```
$ /opt/graalvm-ce-java11-20.0.0/bin/javac Test.java; /opt/graalvm-ce-java11-20.0.0/bin/java -ea Test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: String[].hasArrayElements() failed
    at Test.main(Test.java:14)
```

What am I doing wrong ?..

Answer (score 1):

At best, the documentation is out of date, at worst, this is a bug. You should file an issue for Truffle: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues